# Change the CSS style of selected element using CSS only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a box and I want to change the style, like change the border when a user click on that box.

I know this can be done through JS or jQuery, but is this possible using only CSS?

I tried using :focus and :active, it does changes the style when you click, but on release of the click it reverts the CSS

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
<div class="box"></div>
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #ff0000;

}

.box:active, .box:focus {
    border: 2px solid #00afec;
}
```

I created the Fiddle also to try: **http://jsfiddle.net/cj3LV/**

Please suggest!

Comment: What is the problem with pure javascript?

Comment: No, it isnt possible ;)
This is just possible with JS or jQuery

Comment: This is only possible if you add to the HTML so you can do [the checkbox hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

Comment: Works fine with a text input like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/cj3LV/2/), otherwise you probably want to use [jQuery selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/) for any divs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Trick with a Checkbox in CSS:
Its possible because of following things:

- The Checkbox is hidden.
- If you clicked on the Label you are checked the Checkbox. The Reason is the same value in for="toggle-1" and id="toggle-1"
- This declartion `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .box {  }` matches elements that are siblings of the given element.
  This will match a `.box` element if it's a sibling of `input[type=checkbox]:checked`

http://jsfiddle.net/cj3LV/3/

CSS:

```
.box, .label{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #ff0000;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.label {
    position: absolute;
    display:block; 
    border:0;
}
#toggle-1 { display:none; }


/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .box {
   border: 2px solid #00afec;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="toggle-1" class="label"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div class="box">Click ME!!</div>
```

For more Information you can read here: http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: Fair enough, although the semantics of this is pretty unpalatable.

Comment: Could you kindly explain the principle behind this?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that for="something" and id="something" binds together the elements in terms of the events. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5hzaS/)

**HTML**

```
<div id='clickme'><a href="#clickme">Click Me</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#clickme{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #ff0000;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 100px;
}

#clickme:target
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Edit:** I initially deleted it because there was a better answer. But I was wrong, it can serve.

Answer (score 1):

You might use target but you need to create  a link

http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target